# Setting a different cell color causes previous original color cells to switch to the new cell color in the xlnt library

Tags: c++, excel, colors, libraries

I have some code that gets called when new items are added to a spreadsheet using xlnt that sets the new cells to a green background.

```
void SBOMUpdater::insertNewComponent(workbook& wb, const Component& component, row_t curRow) {
    worksheet sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0);
    sheet.insert_rows(curRow, ONE_ROW);

    cell cell = getCellFromRow(wb, curRow, COMPONENT_VENDOR_NAME);
    cell.value(component.getSupplier());
    cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(xlnt::color::green()));

    cell = getCellFromRow(wb, curRow, COMPONENT_NAME);
    cell.value(component.getName());
    cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(xlnt::color::green()));

    cell = getCellFromRow(wb, curRow, COMPONENT_VERSION);
    cell.value(component.getVersion());
    cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(xlnt::color::green()));

    cell = getCellFromRow(wb, curRow, COMPONENT_LICENSE);
    cell.value(component.getLicense());
    cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(xlnt::color::green()));
}
```

[image]
Later I have some code that adjusts the cell of any column entry that has an updated version # to have a background color of yellow:

```
void SBOMUpdater::updateComponentVersion(workbook& wb, Component& component, row_t curRow) {
    cell cell = getCellFromRow(wb, curRow, COMPONENT_VERSION);
    string version = cell.to_string();

    if (version != component.getVersion()) {
        cell.value(component.getVersion());
        cell.fill(xlnt::fill::solid(xlnt::color::yellow()));
    }
}
```

However, even though there is only one cell in my current functional test, all of the cells that were previously set to green are now set to yellow with this one cell change.
[image]
I have tried to set up workbook named styles (one green and one yellow) thinking that perhaps it was some global setting and I was overwriting the previous green with yellow but that didn't help. There is only one sheet in this workbook.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

As mentioned, I have tried to create named styles and use those but that only slightly complicated the code and had no effect. I originally only passed around a reference to the one sheet but I noticed that even though I could recover the workbook from that to look up the named styles, the styles didn't seem to exist in the recovered workbook. Anyway, I have tried many different combinations of code to try to fix this with no solution.

getCellFromRow is defined as:

```
cell SBOMUpdater::getCellFromRow(workbook& wb, row_t row, column_t column) {
    worksheet sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0);
    cell_reference cellRef{column, row};
    cell cell = sheet[cellRef];
    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the implementation of `getCellFromRow`? Or, if possible, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: ok, thanks for your time. I added the implementation of getCellFromRow

Comment: @YurkoFlisk, thanks for your time. I added the implementation of getCellFromRow

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error on the empty Workbook but unsuccesfully. I.e. if I create cells and immediately update them it works as expected. However, if I loaded the workbook where cells had shared custom style set, I had a similiar error upon updating in Release mode and in Debug it (fortunately) crashed revealing that there is an issue in XLNT implementation. Debugging showed that XLNT internally incorrectly performs reference counting of `xlnt::format_impl` in this case (it is always `1` initially even if cells share it through having the same style).

Comment: @yurkoflisk  Honestly I was hoping it was my defect because the project doesn't seem to be maintained as often. I eventually want to open source this with a friendly license so if you wanted to look at the code directly I can give access. It's on GitHub.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk, I already had to create an unrelated patch to add the inclusion of iostream and limits to number_formatter.cpp since Rocky Linux 9 wouldn't compile without errors. I submitted a comment to the project though.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt/issues/723) on GitHub, maybe if the maintainer returns (or someone else has time) it will be resolved.